# Parse.com Data column type information

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

Is there any way to get the type of a column for a specific class programmatically? In the Unity and .NET documentation I do not see anything indicating that this is a possibility.

Comment: Do you mean DataTable class or just object like, String etc. ?

Comment: Sounds like you may be asking about Reflection, but you'll need to provide more detail about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know if reflection works for the Parse API. It returns generic objects that the developer must know the type of. I only see methods like `Get<T>` in the Parse object class. I also see how to get all the keys, but nothing that contains type information for those keys. http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseObject.htm